# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded / upgrade React-Native 63.5 to 0.71

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I hope someone can help me.

We try to upgrade a React-native app from 0.63.5 to 0.71
But when we followed the recommendations.
our app crash.

At the root level I tried to reduce the complexity as much as possible, I only keep one component.

[image]
App crash with : **Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded** ❌

```
<ActivityIndicator color="#0000ff" size={'small'} />
```

spinner ok ✅

```
<ActivityIndicator color="red" size={'small'} />
```

it's as if now the application can only read colors in string and not in RGB/hex

https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator